# JAXB fails to load file having name containing URL encoded characters

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a file whose path looks like this `/home/jwayne/test/55-0388%25car.xml`. I try to unmarshall the XML back to an object using JAXB as follows.

```
File file = new File("/home/jwayne/test/55-0388%25car.xml");
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Rectangle.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

However, I get a FileNotFoundException (FNFE) with the stacktrace as follows.

```
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jwayne/test/55-0388%car.xml (No such file or directory)]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
...
```

Note that somehow (as suggested by the stacktrace), the unmarshaller has modified the file name from `55-0388%25car.xml` to `55-0388%car.xml`.

Stepping through the code, however, the problem is actually pretty deep: `sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler` has a method `openConnection` that does the following.

```
File var4 = new File(ParseUtil.decode(var1.getPath()));
```

That `sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode` method actually transforms the file path.

Any idea on how to quickly fix this problem (besides renaming the file)? (Note I am using JDK v1.8.0_191).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that there is a `%` that is used to URL encode special characters. For `%` it is `%25`.

What JAXB does internally is that it decodes `%25` to plain `%` and thus the file cannot be found.

Quick (and dirty) solution is to do some string replacing, like:

```
String fileName = "/home/jwayne/test/55-0388%25car.xml": 
fileName = fileName.replace("%25", "%2525");
File file = new File(fileName);
```

This applies whenever there is `%25` in a file name. But I guess this happens to any URL encoded characters. So if there are any other special characters you need some handling for each or some clever regexp solution.

**Update**:

to get around this JAXB behaviour provide it with `InputStream` instead of `File`. So like:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);        
Rectangle r2 = (Rectangle) unmarshaller.unmarshal(fis);
```

Then there is no means for JAXB to alter any URI / filename.

Comment: I'd expect some symmetry in the JAXB and/or Java APIs. Because when I marshal to the XML file, that `%25` is preserved, but when I unmarshal back, it's tampered with. I wouldn't mind if there was the same treatment going either way in regards to file paths. Thanks for the tip. But yes, you are right, these file names are a result of URL encoding, and there will be many more cases like this one. Would be nice if there was a generic approach to resolve. I suppose the easiest thing is just to rename these files.

Comment: @JaneWayne Yes. I'm a bit surprised also, never run into this kind of problems with the impl I used. But see my update soon. Found another workaround.